# merge arrays with same value of key

Tags: php, arrays

I use php **glob** function for get images in sub directories and I dont know how many files exist in each directory

directory name is `id` and I want to categorize all images in directories in one array

```
$arr = [];
$dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/gulets";
$files = glob($dir."/*/*_gulet_o_*");
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fullname = str_replace($dir."/", "", $file);
    $name = explode("/", $fullname);
    $name1 = array('id'=>$name[0],'name'=>$name[1]);
    $arr[] = $name1;
}   
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);

[
{
"id": "10",
"name": "asdsad_gulet_o_1.jpg"
},
{
"id": "10",
"name": "wqes_gulet_o_10.jpg"
},
{
"id": "10",
"name": "qwsdf_gulet_o_11.jpg"
},
{
"id": "10",
"name": "sdce_gulet_o_12.jpg"
},
{
"id": "11",
"name": "fsdsc_gulet_o_13.jpg"
},
{
"id": "11",
"name": "drfvc_gulet_o_14.jpg"
},
{
"id": "12",
"name": "dsyjhk_gulet_o_15.jpg"
},
.
.
```

and I need change it like this :

```
    [
    {
    "id": "10",
    "name1": "asdsad_gulet_o_1.jpg",
    "name2": "wqes_gulet_o_10.jpg",
    "name3": "qwsdf_gulet_o_11.jpg"
    "name4": "sdce_gulet_o_12.jpg"
    },
    {
    "id": "11",
    "name1": "fsdsc_gulet_o_13.jpg"
    "name2": "drfvc_gulet_o_14.jpg"
    },
    {
    "id": "12",
    "name1": "dsyjhk_gulet_o_15.jpg"
.
.
```

Comment: you can't have 2 or more same key names `name`.

Comment: @roullie yes I correct key names in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating indexes like `name1`, `name2`, `name3` etc is not useful. You should create subarray with index `names` and there put your names. Try code like this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'qwerty'),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'asdf'),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'hjkl'),
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'cvbnm'),
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'yuiop'),
);

$groups = array();

foreach($array as $singleRow)
{
    if(!isset($groups[$singleRow['id']]))
        $groups[$singleRow['id']] = array('id'=>$singleRow['id'], 'names'=>array());

    $groups[$singleRow['id']]['names'][] = $singleRow['name'];
}
$json = json_encode(array_values($groups));     
var_dump($json);
```

It outputs:

```
[{"id":1,"names":["qwerty","cvbnm","yuiop"]},{"id":2,"names":["asdf","hjkl"]}]
```

Comment: @Mohammad b, I modified my answer: instead of printing array prints json.

Comment: why it doesnt sort from 1 to 100 it start from 10 then 101 I need to sort and key of each array equal with id to use it in angularjs

Answer (score 2):

you want something like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $a) {
  $new_arr[$a['id']]['names'][] = $a['name'];
}
```

Comment: it works nice , but why names is into bracket [] instead of {} ?

Comment: @Mohammadb, because names is an array.

Answer (score 0):

instead of -

```
$name1 = array('id'=>$name[0],'name'=>$name[1]);
$arr[] = $name1;
```

you can use something like -

```
$nameKey = 'name' . $name[0];
$name1 = array('id'=>$name[0],$nameKey =>$name[1]);
if (!empty($arr[$name[0]])) {
  $arr[$name[0]] = $arr[$name[0]] + $name1;
}
else {
  $arr[$name[0]] = $name1;
}
```

and after end of foreach() loop do -

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: it changed key names but return only one value of each key

Comment: again it doesnt work and return one name for each key